# Upgrading to Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE + Thymeleaf 3.0.11.RELEASE, thymeleaf/layout stopped working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

After migrating Spring-Boot from `1.5.3.RELEASE` to `2.2.2.RELEASE`, Thymeleaf stopped working.

### pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

...

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I've followed [Thymeleaf 3 migration guide](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html) + read [Spring-Boot release](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-webflux-template-engines), but no success...

### Template fragment (Thymeleaf 3.0 `layout:decorate`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html th:lang="${#locale}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4"
    xmlns:layout="https://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorate="layout">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div layout:fragment="content">
```

`http://localhost/index` path comparison:

### Code fragment (1.5.3.RELEASE)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">

<head>

    <title>APLLICATION</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'/><![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="Application description" />
    <meta name="fragment" content="text" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    ...
```

### Code fragment (2.2.2.RELEASE)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:layout="https://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorate="layout">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div layout:fragment="content">
...
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT:**

@Marged, Models are set:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/index").setViewName("index");
        ...
    }

}
```

Context-path is by default (`/`)

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ AppConfig.class })
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("foo.bar")
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *stopped working*? What exactly you do? What do you observe?

Comment: It's not resolving thymeleaf commands.. e.i: templace code `<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" th:lang="${#locale}">` should be interpreted into `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">`, but as you can see Thymeleaf doesn't work...

Comment: How do you set the model and the context ?

Comment: @Marged I've updated my question. Check please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue seems to be related to [Thymeleaf Layout Dialect](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html) (see #4). Spring-Boot `1.5.3.RELEASE` supports it out of the box but `2.2.2.RELEASE` doesn't. This is even stated in [dialect's documentation](https://ultraq.github.io/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/Installation.html):

> The layout dialect is already included as part of the Thymeleaf starter pack in Spring Boot 1.x, but has been removed in Spring Boot 2, hence the additional config step for Spring Boot 2 users above.

Following installation steps from above link should be helpful, i.a.:

- Add maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

- Add Extra `@Bean` to you configuration:

```java
@Bean
public LayoutDialect layoutDialect() {
    return new LayoutDialect();
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!!! Thank you very much, it has solved my headache